# Agregar filas a un datatable de asp llenado a partir de una base de datos

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

En mi aplicación tengo un data table que lleno a partir de un registro de una base de datos, tomando el siguiente método:

```
Public Shared Function RetData(query as String) As DataTable
    Dim conn As New Connection()
    Dim tabla As New DataTable()
    Try
        conn.Connection.Open()

        Dim strcom As String = quer
        Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(strcom, conn.Connection())
        sqlDa.Fill(tabla)
        conn.Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        conn.Connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return tabla
End Function
```

Este registro se guarda en mi data table, posteriormente lo guardo en una session de tipo datatable para mostrarle después en un grid.

```
Protected Sub btns_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btns.Click
    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    tbl = clsUtilities.RetData("Select top 1 * from tabla")
    If tbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim nrow As DataRow = tbl.Rows(0)
        lblsnum.Text = nrow("Serial_Number").ToString()
        Session("antenna") = tbl
    Else
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    tbl = Session("antenna")
    tbl.Columns.Add("Reason")
    tbl.Columns.Add("Out of the box")
    Dim row As DataRow
    row = tbl.NewRow
    Dim rowscount = tbl.Rows.Count
    For i = 0 To rowscount - 1
        tbl.Rows(i)("Reason") = ddlreason.SelectedItem.ToString
        tbl.Rows(i)("Out of the box") = ddlout.SelectedItem.ToString
    Next

    gvAntennasAdded.DataSource = tbl
    gvAntennasAdded.DataBind()
    Session("antenna") = tbl

End Sub
```

Sin embargo a ese grid le seguiré agregando registros lo que hará que cada vez que agregue uno se añada una nueva fila. **¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?**

Answer (score 1):

Analizando tu inconveniente lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
Dim tblGlobal As New DataTable
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

tblGlobal = Session("antenna")

If tblGlobal .Rows.Count=0 then

tblGlobal .Columns.Add("Reason")
tblGlobal .Columns.Add("Out of the box")

End If

Dim row As DataRow
row = tblGlobal.NewRow
Dim rowscount = tblGlobal.Rows.Count
For i = 0 To rowscount - 1
    tblGlobal.Rows(i)("Reason") = ddlreason.SelectedItem.ToString
    tblGlobal.Rows(i)("Out of the box") = ddlout.SelectedItem.ToString
Next


gvAntennasAdded.DataSource = tblGlobal 
gvAntennasAdded.DataBind()
Session("antenna") = tblGlobal 
End Sub
```

Si entendi el problema, la solución es crear el DataTable de forma global y validar cada vez que vaya a agregar uno para saber si se van crear las columnas.
En caso de que sea web tu proyecto puedes tener una clase estatica para crear el datatable global.

Espero que te sirva